# iOS Google Maps SDK Crashing

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

Hello I'm having a problem, I have Integrated GMS on my app and it keeps on crashing when I'm trying to repeatedly trying to add entries that requires address.

Google Issues: https://issuetracker.google.com/113978690

What is the incorrect behavior that you are experiencing?

- App is crashing when loading the view with Google Maps

What should happen instead?

- Should load without a problem

CallStack:

- gmscore::renderer::MutableImageData::ProvideTextureImage() + 84

Steps to reproduce the problem:

- Repeat adding new entry until the time google maps crashes
- Operating system version: iOS 11.4.1 [15G77]
- Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 2.7.0 / iOS 11.4
- Hardware model: iphoneX

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 14.52101057,longitude: 121.06712508,zoom: zoomLevel)
    mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: camera)
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    mapView.delegate = self

    do {
        // Set the map style by passing a valid JSON string.
        mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(jsonString: kMapStyle)
    } catch {
        NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
    }


    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 50
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.delegate = self

    self.view.addSubview(mapView)
    self.view.addSubview(UserBar)

}
```

Screencast of phone when the crash occurred: [Video](https://bugsee-store-prod-west2.s3.amazonaws.com/5b87addfbc5ba83d782129b3/5b87adecbc5ba83d782129bb/issues/5b8ed3ff85422730c9f159d3/5b8efe0885422730c9f16682/screen.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIA4CQYODQT64X5JJXF&Expires=1536228107&Signature=cUF2uppW6OAAqAeST1ghVDMEdoo%3D&x-amz-security-token=FQoGZXIvYXdzEF4aDB5u7mvlvzx2qN6h3CK3AwuTQAbbNW0OlMAFwmBaB08TNr2%2BPrb%2B80AOGdRQmh%2BkrJ5ZRlvJxnkqCaA1IJdD4r10wAG4xsmGr9RaZwTyV51RNRzhxtJyhGLwGwRdMPcYSAzB4e6LEW9oDPisy%2BsiUW426Ztm644xwLS0XcfIHm2BYn3y9S8I6oiHY%2BzkMH3QY7RIInJvxgqwp8NR6mGToc8Wizj1wXbqlMulRJA6i1Mw%2BdmfHp9S%2FGINwETY0gBHvMq2u5y5yd%2B6inLahMjRf6O%2BsEKcwpI%2F7BX1YNWST6yf1N9GWOscf%2FmqmvlubLM9Zem679uhOnzdYbLkQpZNEHgx3Kq1saRyBRP58dO6wS3HZtJN9WBUjD%2BjQAr8MQ4Qyiw1H%2ByuAMRvkQf7vMeNaBI%2BxWoJ5ZxjbUYMRodygZv0zJ8PfAG2iCEU1M0RYjy5BorZNCussHun5To7nMgbK2cbA2xZImX5BcpM1RKnKRb4mllOoAU2Kc3seYgsiy4kNNnUZL2PtzyuvUx%2BqwUZf9edyerf9%2BaiO2Wt1bN5iGyvcLHT3RrmZOIWkShijQ3pjqC4sjwDOMTx9Xu07iTl0nBGJQbw0%2BAo87693AU%3D)

Comment: you are adding entries to the google maps. what does that mean, BTW ?

Comment: Did you find any solution any solution?